io.fabric8.api.fabricexception: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.checkoutconflictexception: checkout conflict with files
Hello, I have a problem with a Jboss Fuse container.
Detail:
I am from a linux server.
There is not much documentation on the project, so I am following the lines you have left, so there is a line where it says I should copy a broker.xml and paste it to the path:
fuse\fuseBrk01-pro\jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084\fabric\import\fabric\profiles\mq\base.profile

and then use this command:
profile-edit --pid io.fabric8.mq.fabric.server-hq-broker/config=profile:bg-broker.xml mq-broker-masterslave.hq-broker

but when I apply this, it deletes the file, and then in the log console, it comes out that it can't find the file.
I tried to edit the file manually but I get this error:
io.fabric8.api.fabricexception: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.checkoutconflictexception: checkout conflict with files:fabric/profiles/mq/base.profile/broker.xml


first I tried copying a file and pasting it into the path described above
fuse\fuseBrk01-pro\jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084\fabric\import\fabric\profiles\mq\base.profile
and then use the command
profile-edit --pid io.fabric8.mq.fabric.server-hq-broker/config=profile:bg-broker.xml mq-broker-masterslave.hq-broker

I tried to edit the file from console, text editor, but I got another error:
io.fabric8.api.fabricexception: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.checkoutconflictexception: checkout conflict with files:fabric/profiles/mq/base.profile/broker.xml

The purpose of this file or edit broker configuration is to prevent the fuse from crashing or stopping when trying to process a multi-item file, be it an electronic receipt.
This is why we try to increase the memory space.

Fuse 6.2.1.redhat-084 is an ancient version of Fuse 6 and is no longer supported.
You should not touch fabric\import\fabric\profiles directory because it's managed by Fuse 6 patching mechanism.


I am following the lines you have left, so there is a line where it says I should copy a broker.xml and paste it to the path
where do you see this instruction?


The problem is that the electronic invoicing system is handled with that version of Fuse.
At the point where I try to replace the broker.xml file
At the moment of replacing it and using the mentioned command, in the logs of the console, it indicates me that it does not find the file, because for some reason it deletes it, and therefore the message that it does not find the broker.xml file.

As I said - you should NOT put files there in existing runtime. This directly is only a source of initial profiles where fabric is created. And I'm certain you've created the fabric instance long time ago... There's entire documentation about profile management here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2.1/html/fabric_guide/index
